# ajax in asp.net via scriptmanger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

first of all forgive me my poor english it's not my lang.

I am trying to work with ajax as follows:

I created a webservice and a web page that calls to a method in the webservice.
I am trying to call the service like this:

```
<button onclick="run()" formmethod="post">Sample</button>
```

The problem is that if this button is inside the form, it doesn't work because it posts back. If the button is outside of the form it works.

How can I put this button inside the form and still have it call the web service?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking the problem is the button initalizes a submit before the service is called.

What I would suggest would be to use an `input` button and handle the `click` event:

```
<input type='button' onclick='CallService();' value='Sample' id='btnSample' />
```

in your script have:

```
function CallService(){
    {ServiceName}.run({parameter},CallComplete);
}

function CallComplete(){
    document.form.submit();
}
```

I would say do it this way so that you know your service is being called before the form is submitted.